# Как с помощью jquery назначить класс последнему блоку в строке и всем блокам последней строки

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.mb {
display: table;
}

.bl {
width:100px;
float:left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
text-align:center;
padding: 10px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb">
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
<div class="bl">
<a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
</div>
</div>
```

В зависимости от ширины экрана, последний блок в строке будет меняться, также как и количество блоков в последней строке. 
Требуется вычислить последний блок в строке и добавить ему дополнительный класс "lastblock", а также вычислить все блоки в последней строке и тоже добавить им дополнительный класс "lastrow".

Подскажите, как это реализовать с помощью jquery если это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно есть вариант изящнее, но пока могу предложить такой.

Суть решения заключается в следующем. Очевидно, что последний элемент в списке будет находится в последней строке. Значит элементы, у которых точно такой же `offset.top`, как и у последнего элемента, также будут находится в последней строке.

Начнем проверять элементы с конца списка. И первый элемент, у которого `offset.top` отличается от `offset.top` последнего элемента в списке, будет последним элементом в предпоследней строке, а его `offset.left` будет такой же как у всех последних элементов в строках.

Полный код примера

```js
var $list = $('.mb .bl');

$(window).resize(function() {

  var top = $list.last().offset().top; // верхняя координата элементов последнего ряда
  var left; // левая граница последнего элемента в ряду (пока неизвестна)

  // начинаем проверять элементы последней строки с конца списка
  for (var i = $list.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var $current = $list.eq(i);
    $current.removeClass('lastrow lastblock')

    // проверяем верхнюю координату, если равна top, 
    // значит текущий элемент из последнего ряда
    if ($current.offset().top === top) {
      $current.addClass('lastrow');
      continue;
    }

    // первый элемент, у которого верхняя координата не равна top
    // является последним элементом в предпоследней строке
    $current.addClass('lastblock');
    left = $current.offset().left;

    // чтобы последний элемент получил класс `lastblock`, 
    // если он стоит в последнем ряду
    if ($list.last().offset().left === left) {
      $list.last().addClass('lastblock');
    }

    break;
  }

  // продолжаем проверять элементы, 
  // только теперь ищем последние элементы в строке
  for (i -= 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var $current = $list.eq(i);
    $current.removeClass('lastrow lastblock')

    if ($current.offset().left === left) {
      $current.addClass('lastblock')
    }
  }
});

$(window).trigger('resize')
```

```css
.mb {
  display: table;
}

.bl {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lastrow a {
  color: red
}

.lastblock a {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mb">
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Не гарантируется, что это решение будет работать, если размеры блоков будут различны.*

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как нужно! Отдельное спасибо за то, что дали поэтапные пояснения, как работает скрипт!

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, что добавить в ваш скрипт что бы у последнего блока в последней строке было оба класса и "lastblock" и "lastrow" - не смотря на данные вами пояснения к скрипту - не как не получается, где-то что-то неверно делаю - синтаксис толком незнаю..

Comment: в дополнение к предыдущему сообщению, как сделать что бы у последнего блока в последней строке к  классу "lastrow" добавился класс "lastblock" при условии что его (последний блок в последней строке) координаты  совпадают с блоком в строке выше  у которого тоже класс  "lastblock", если он не "дотягивает" до правого края, то остается просто класс "lastrow"  как сейчас, просто у блоков с классом "lastblock" определенное оформление, и последний блок в последней строке выбивается из общего ряда

Comment: @Slava обновил ответ. Кстати, изначально эта логика была, но я убрал ее из ответа, так как посчитал что она не нужна.

Comment: Ай спасибо! Как нужно все работает! Убил 3 часа пытаясь самостоятельно сделать! Отдельно спасибо за оперативный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Можно узнавать ширину блока и контейнера и просто считать количество ячеек в ряду. При этом не производить манипуляций, если не изменилось количество.

```js
var itemsInRow = 0;

$(window).resize(function() {
  var blw = $('.mb .bl').outerWidth();
  var mbw = $('.mb').outerWidth();
  if (itemsInRow !== Math.floor(mbw / blw)) {
    itemsInRow = Math.floor(mbw / blw);
    $('.mb .bl.lastblock').removeClass('lastblock');
    $('.mb .bl.lastrow').removeClass('lastrow');
    $('.mb .bl:nth-child('+itemsInRow+'n)').addClass('lastblock');
    $('.mb .bl.lastblock').last().nextAll().addClass('lastrow');
    if (!$('.lastrow').length) {
      $('.mb .bl:gt('+($('.mb .bl').length - itemsInRow-1)+')').addClass('lastrow');
    }
  }
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

```css
.mb {
  display: table;
}

.bl {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lastblock a {
  color: green
}

.lastrow a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mb">
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bl">
    <a href="#" title="#">Ссылка </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный вариант, но если у блока .mb задать ширину 100%, а у блока .bl width: 25%;  min-width:100px; то почему-то скрипт начинает считать с ошибкой и добавляет классы не тем блокам, которые являются последними и в последней строке..  При этом растягивая и сужая окно браузера временами все становится как нужно.. Не могу понять почему так, за что он запинается в расчетах?

Comment: да. но ответ был под ваш css с фиксированной шириной

Comment: Это да, с фиксированной шириной блока .bl - работает как часы при любой ширине экрана. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так, получим ширину mb, получим все все блоки bl запишем их в массив, а также заведем переменную счетчик ширины = 0,  затем идем по массиву и достаем свойство ширины у каждого блока, и плюсуем в счетчик, при этом каждый рас сравниваем получившеюся сумму с шириной bl и как только наша сумма станет больше ширины mb ,это значит что мы перешли на новую строку и значит ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ элемент был тот которому и нужно назначить нужный класс, назначаем нужный класс, и так идем до конца, только после каждого раза когда ваша сумма больше ширины bl не забываем сбрасывать счетчик ширины, то есть записать новое значение к которому мы теперь будем плюсовать, это значения есть ширина ТЕКУЩЕГО элемента. Теперь у нас каждый последний элемент имеет нужный класс.

Дальше берем тот же массив и идем в обратном порядке также плюсуем ширину каждого, по скольку это последние элементы, следовательно это последней ряд, назначаем каждому элементу необходимый класс до того времени пока не перейдем на следующий ряд, то есть пока наша сумма не станет больше чем ширина mb. Да с последним рядом может оказаться нюанс, в том случае если последний ряд не занимает всю ширину bl  но в таком случае можно сделать так, поскольку у нас уже есть классы на каждом последнем элементе в ряде, мы можем получить новый массив в котором  можно использовать новые классы как метки и бежать с конца массива до первого элемента с такой меткой, при этом назначать всем элементам нужные классы)

Надеюсь понятно все описал, и ничего не забыл) пробуйте